# How to compare the socioeconomic status between two populations after applying multiple correspondence analysis?

Tags: chi-squared-test, group-differences, pre-post-comparison, correspondence-analysis, social-science

I have two datasets of two populations (before and after)
with the task to create socioeconomic quintiles. Through many variables such as household assets and household quality, I used MCA (R language) and I was able to assign every household to a socioeconomic quintile. But what I am tasked now is to know if the socioeconomic status has improved/worsened/or nothing has changed. I am not able to figure out a way to execute such comparison.

What I did was after creating the socioeconomic groups of the first dataset, I used the ind.supp argumemt to assign the second dataset to socioeconomic groups using the scale of the first dataset. But I'm not sure if it is correct. Thansk.

Comment: Is MCA multiple correspondence analysis? If so, state it (as an edit to the posts, as comments are easily overseen) and maybe add the tag [tag:correspondence-analysis]